# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

When I run the flutter project on the android emulator I got this error log.

This error log comes when I run any flutter project.

Don't know what happens. Any help?

This is the error log (What went wrong):

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not download flutter_embedding_debug.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab)
      > Could not get resource 'https://storage.flutter-io.cn/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
   > Could not download x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab)
      > Could not get resource 'https://storage.flutter-io.cn/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab/x86_debug-1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
   > Could not download x86_64_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab)
      > Could not get resource 'https://storage.flutter-io.cn/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
```

This is my project-level **build.gradle** file

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```